# Kext reference from connected user-space clients

Tags: macos, dependencies, driver, kernel-extension, xnu

I'm using Kext which provides services to one or more user-space clients that communicate with it using iokit service.

I'd like that each such client will take reference on the kext, so that it wouldn't be possible to unload the kext as long as there are still available clients.

according to the documentation I can use `IOServiceOpen` and `IOConnectAddRef`, but it's still possible to unload the driver using `kextunload`.

`kextstat` also shows that no references are taken on the driver, those are references by other drivers as it mentioned in the documentation, but I thought that the above commands will do the trick.

```
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version)                UUID <Linked Against>
1     100 0xffffff7f80a46000 0x9d90     0x9d90      com.apple.kpi.bsd (16.7.0)    410B3B98-9DAB-4590-9086-7C57A5B3099A
2       8 0xffffff7f80fc3000 0x3940     0x3940      com.apple.kpi.dsep (16.7.0)   FA744B47-913C-4B5D-8C16-2F8005D85935
3     127 0xffffff7f80a04000 0x21040    0x21040     com.apple.kpi.iokit (16.7.0)  80F2DA67-C67B-4583-9B09-082DB11F69FC
...
170     0 0xffffff7f80a04000 0x21040    0x32120     com.my-driver.nsl (1.0.0)     53390CCD-55F0-315F-BBD7-21645800E4A0
```

what should I do in order to increase the #Refs from the above chart ?

EDIT: In apple documentation, it's possible to state your kext dependencies in the info.plist file.

> Any KEXT can declare that it is dependent upon any other KEXT. The developer lists these dependencies in the OSBundleLibraries dictionary in the module’s property list file.

However, I'd like to do the other way around by marking refs from other entities to my kext, and those entities aren't necessarily drivers - In windows they all called services, and one can easy link between 2 such services disregarding if they're user-space processes or kernel modules.

thnaks